# Angular2 directive property binding

Tags: angular

I have a directive that either shows or hides a sidebar on click.  I want to create an option to show the sidebar or hide the sidebar on i.

My component.html:

```
<button class="sidebar-minimizer" type="button" appSidebarMinimizer [minimizeSide] = "open" appBrandMinimizer></button>
```

I created a property `[minimizeSide] = "'open'"`

My component.ts

```
export class AppSidebarMinimizerComponent {
  open = "open";

}
```

My directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSidebarMinimizer]'
})
export class SidebarMinimizeDirective {
  @Input() minimizeSide:string;
  constructor() {
    if (this.minimizeSide == "open"){
      document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('brand-minimized');
    }
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  toggleOpen($event: any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('sidebar-minimized');
  }
}
```

The click function works fine but it doesn't work while init.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the reason to your problem are listed below:

- `@Input` field will be updated when first change detection got executed
- Directive, as also Component, will be constructed first and then runs life-hook (`OnChanges` => `OnInit` and so on)of itself.

So you won't get value bound to `@Input` unless `OnChange` life hook of your directive got executed. You can move the initialization code block to directive's `OnInit` life hook.

```
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.minimizeSide == "open"){
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('brand-minimized');
  }
}
```